# mongodb rollback of primary when write concern is 1

Tags: mongodb

Take this circumstances when a client writes to a server in replica set mode:

1. Successful write & acknowledgement
2. Unsuccessful and error.

If **1.** happens but right after that the primary goes down - before sending data to secondary nodes, there will be troubles. When going back in, it *will roll back* and although the client got an acknowledgement, the data is dismissed.

**Question**

- why does it roll back instead of sending the data to the remaining nodes when the primary is back in?  Does this happen because of an election? And what if the result of the election is the same node?

---

Conjecture: The server goes down, triggers an election, and a different server takes place. When it catches up the new primary, the written message it's not in the oplog, and I guess they continue with different oplogs?

I know we can change this behaviour using majority but would like to understand why this roll back happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB implements single-master replication, which mandates that only one server is the authoritative source of replication at any time. If it were to replicate the data that is rolled back, it would have to merge it into the new primary and this is complicated and error-prone as the data could have been changed multiple times while the old primary was down.

When a primary goes down and later rejoins the cluster, it reconciles its own copy of the oplog with the one that is in the server that is currently the primary. Since other write operations could have happened in the meantime on the new primary, the new authoritative source of replication is the oplog of the new primary. So, the old primary has to purge its oplog of any operations that are not present in the oplog of the new primary and these are rolled back.

If no primary was available in the cluster when the server rejoins, election takes care of selecting the server with the newest copy of the data (based on the timestamp of the last operation in the oplog). This becomes the new primary and all other servers will sync their oplog to this. So, if the old primary becomes primary again and no newer writes happened in the cluster, then it will not rollback.

Rolled back data is not lost but put aside on a file so that it can be examined and eventually recovered by DBAs if needed. However, you should consider the nature of the data you are storing and, if it is crucial that rollbacks never happen, then use the appropriate write concern to ensure additional copies are made to guarantee it is never lost.

Comment: I can't quite understand the first paragraph, but the rest was crystal clear. Thanks a a lot @Emir.

Comment: It is just an introduction to the next paragraph. Single-master replication is the way MongoDB replication works. The other alternative is multi-master replication, but on a multi-master system you will have data conflicts and therefore you need a way to fix these conflicts. It is not different from a source control system like git. If two developers change the same file, you get a conflict, and somebody has to merge the two versions.